# JavaScript Snake game

Tags: javascript, beginner, snake-game

I recently followed a tutorial on a JavaScript snake game. I tried to improve that game by adding bad fruit which will make your snakes tail incredibly long.

```js
//constants
var COLS = 26,
  ROWS = 26;
//IDs
var EMPTY = 0,
  SNAKE = 1,
  FRUIT = 2,
  BADFRUIT = 3;
//direction
var LEFT = 0,
  UP = 1,
  RIGHT = 2,
  DOWN = 3;
//game objects
var canvas, ctx, keystate, frames;
// Key Codes
var KEY_LEFT = 37,
  KEY_UP = 38,
  KEY_RIGHT = 39,
  KEY_DOWN = 40


var grid = {
  width: null,
  height: null,
  _grid: null,

  init: function(d, c, r) {
    this.width = c;
    this.height = r;
    this._grid = [];

    for (var x = 0; x < c; x++) {
      this._grid.push([]);
      for (var y = 0; y < r; y++) {
        this._grid[x].push(d);
      }
    }
  },


  set: function(val, x, y) {
    this._grid[x][y] = val;

  },

  get: function(x, y) {
    return this._grid[x][y]

  },
}
var snake = {
  direction: null,
  last: null,

  _queue: null,

  init: function(d, x, y) {
    this.direction = d;

    this._queue = [];
    this.insert(x, y);
  },

  insert: function(x, y) {
    // unshift prepends an element to an array
    this._queue.unshift({
      x: x,
      y: y
    });
    this.last = this._queue[0];
  },

  remove: function() {
    return this._queue.pop();
  },
}

function setAlwaysBadFood() {
  var empty = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
      if (grid.get(x, y) === EMPTY) {
        empty.push({
          x: x,
          y: y
        });
      }
    }
  }

  var randpos = empty[Math.round(Math.random() * (empty.length - 1))];
  grid.set(BADFRUIT, randpos.x, randpos.y);

}

function setBadFood() {
  var randomBadFruit = Math.round(Math.random() * 10)
  console.log(randomBadFruit)
  console.log("WHY ARE YOU LOOKING HERE!   >:(")
  if (randomBadFruit === 9 || randomBadFruit === 8) {
    var empty = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
        if (grid.get(x, y) === EMPTY) {
          empty.push({
            x: x,
            y: y
          });
        }
      }
    }

    var randpos = empty[Math.round(Math.random() * (empty.length - 1))];
    grid.set(BADFRUIT, randpos.x, randpos.y);
    console.log(randomBadFruit)
  }
}

function setFood() {
  var empty = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
      if (grid.get(x, y) === EMPTY) {
        empty.push({
          x: x,
          y: y
        });
      }
    }
  }

  var randpos = empty[Math.round(Math.random() * (empty.length - 1))];
  grid.set(FRUIT, randpos.x, randpos.y);

}




function main() {
  canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = COLS * 35;
  canvas.height = ROWS * 35;
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  frames = 0
  keystate = {};

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
    keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
  });
  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
    delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
  });
  init();
  loop();
}

function init() {
  grid.init(EMPTY, COLS, ROWS);

  var sp = {
    x: Math.floor(COLS / 2),
    y: ROWS - 1
  };
  snake.init(UP, sp.x, sp.y);
  grid.set(SNAKE, sp.x, sp.y);

  setBadFood();
  setFood();

}

function loop() {
  update();
  draw();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
}

function update() {
  frames++;

  if (keystate[KEY_LEFT] && snake.direction !== RIGHT) {
    snake.direction = LEFT;
  }
  if (keystate[KEY_UP] && snake.direction !== DOWN) {
    snake.direction = UP;
  }
  if (keystate[KEY_RIGHT] && snake.direction !== LEFT) {
    snake.direction = RIGHT;
  }
  if (keystate[KEY_DOWN] && snake.direction !== UP) {
    snake.direction = DOWN;
  }
  if (frames % 5 === 0) {
    var nx = snake.last.x
    var ny = snake.last.y

    switch (snake.direction) {
      case LEFT:
        nx--;
        break;
      case UP:
        ny--;
        break;
      case RIGHT:
        nx++;
        break;
      case DOWN:
        ny++;
        break;


    }

    if (0 > nx || nx > grid.width - 1 ||
      0 > ny || ny > grid.height - 1 ||
      grid.get(nx, ny) === SNAKE
    ) {
      return init();
    }
    if (grid.get(nx, ny) === BADFRUIT) {
      var tail = {
        x: nx,
        y: ny
      };
      for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        snake.insert(tail.x, tail.y);
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setAlwaysBadFood();
      }

    }

    if (grid.get(nx, ny) === FRUIT) {
      var tail = {
        x: nx,
        y: ny
      };
      snake.insert(tail.x, tail.y);
      snake.insert(tail.x, tail.y);
      snake.insert(tail.x, tail.y);
      setFood();
      setBadFood();
      setAlwaysBadFood();


    } else {
      var tail = snake.remove();
      grid.set(EMPTY, tail.x, tail.y);
      tail.x = nx;
      tail.y = ny;
    }


    grid.set(SNAKE, tail.x, tail.y);

    snake.insert(tail.x, tail.y);


  }
}


function draw() {
  // calculate tile-width and -height
  var tw = canvas.width / grid.width;
  var th = canvas.height / grid.height;
  // iterate through the grid and draw all cells
  for (var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
      // sets the fillstyle depending on the id of
      // each cell
      switch (grid.get(x, y)) {
        case EMPTY:
          ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
          break;
        case SNAKE:
          ctx.fillStyle = "#0ff";
          break;
        case FRUIT:
          ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
          break;
        case BADFRUIT:
          ctx.fillStyle = "#000066"
      }
      ctx.fillRect(x * tw, y * th, tw, th);
    }
  }
}


// start and run the game
main();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Simple Snake Game</title>
  <style>
    canvas {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      margin: 0;
      top: 0 bottom: 0 right: 0 left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>
```

What do you think? I'm trying to make the snake go faster but I can't do that.
I don't know what happend but the controls do not work in the stack snippet
sorry for that!

Comment: You can convert this into [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in your post.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer i did that but now the controls don't work ):

Answer (score -1):

i would use `let` instead of `var`, and the syntax `update(){}` instead of `function: update(){}` (considering the ES6 standard).

Comment: There is nothing in this question indicating that the author is targeting ECMAScript 6.

Comment: i'm new to SO, this type of answers is wrong? It's a way of improve his code isn't? @200_success